# Eclipse: Change mouse back button?

Tags: eclipse, mouse

My Eclipse installation (Luna, 4.4) maps the mouse back button to "Last Edit Location" (<kbd>Qtrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>). It trips me up all the time. What I really want is for the back button to do "Back to ..." (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>). Is that possible to change?

Answer (score -2):

This is already reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47099). Although I don't see any reason to avoid the keyboard shortcut at all

Comment: When my hand is on the mouse, it infinitely faster to click the back button with my thumb, than releasing the mouse, hitting the left key, then re-positioning hand on mouse.
Thanks for the link.